# How to wait for a particular time interval for an event in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Here is a basic pygame code-

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

try:
    while True:
        e = pygame.event.wait()
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise StopIteration
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:


except StopIteration:
    pass

pygame.quit()
```

What I want to do is that when the User leaves the mouse button and the MOUSEBUTTONUP event is triggered, I want to wait for a while to check for any MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event before i execute the commands in the MOUSEBUTTONUP block.

Basically I want to wait for maybe 2 seconds after MOUSEBUTTONUP event is triggered and if there is no MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event during that period I will go on to execute the commands in MOUSEBUTTONUP. However if there is a MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event during those 2 seconds I will execute the commands in MOUSEBUTTONDOWN.

Any ideas on how to achieve this behavior will be welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sleep()`.

For example:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

[Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm)

Comment: In sleep I would have to give a fixed time interval during which pygame wouldn't detect any events. I want the program to start executing immediately if the user clicks the mouse during the 2 second pause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `time.time()` method of `time` module. It returns the current time in referenced to epoch as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).

> `time.time()`
>
> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

To wait for user specified time, the following code should work fine:

```
import time

max_time = int(raw_input('Enter the amount of seconds you want to run this: '))
start_time = time.time()  # remember when we started
while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:
    do_stuff()
```